# Simple Alternatives to Object-Relational Mapping for Android/SQLite

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for simple techniques for getting OOP and RDBMS's to work well together.

I'd like to keep it as simple as possible, so no automatic code generation or ORM packages like [ormlite](http://ormlite.com/), but perhaps just POJOs, one for each DB table, with methods like fetchOne(int db_row_id) and fetchAll() that return a cursor.

The problem I keep running into is where to put methods that query two or more tables in a join, since the POJO representing a table has to then have pretty much as much knowledge about other tables as well.

The only alternative I can think of is to just have one class for handling the ORM that has probably around 50-100 methods, each doing its own query across one or many tables and returning a plain Cursor.

Yuk!!

Comment: This question would be more appropriately asked in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/; SO is typically for discussing specific problems with specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not in love with the way I'm doing it, but I usually make a class that represents each table and then I make "provider" classes for all my access (CRUD operations).

So, for example, let's say I had a GameState class and a PlayerInfo class that both represent tables in the db.  GameState could have a `List<PlayerInfo>`.  I could either have my GameStateProvider have the ability to do the joins and populate my `List<PlayerInfo>`, or have a PlayerInfoProvider as well and pass a reference in to my GameStateProvider's get method(s) - I usually do the latter.  My POJO's that represent my db objects also usually have a constructor that takes a Cursor.

I'm not in love with this solution, but it keeps all my classes to a minimum of methods and keeps them readable and not too tightly bound to each other.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to keep it as simple as possible

The problem is, this is not a simple task. That's the reason why people use ORM libraries, and why those libraries are so big.

> perhaps just POJOs, one for each DB table, with methods like fetchOne(int db_row_id) and fetchAll()

I can see where you're going with this. Don't go there! You'll wind up with miles of spaghetti code. I've seen it, and it ain't pretty. You should either use an ORM library, or else figure out some way to store your data that doesn't use a relational database.

Comment: Thanks - The thing is, as discussed in [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user/browse_thread/thread/49b4681c8a2fe692) it's still not an ideal solution, I think I should make use of Android's Cursor as far as possible.

Comment: I have a lot of experience with Java, just not on Android. Would Hibernate or OpenJPA be workable solutions? Or are they too heavy to run on a mobile device?

Comment: Since android runs Dalvik and not Java Bytecode, no libraries which depend on bytecode generation will work. This eliminates Hibernate, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using an object database as db4o could be an alternative, it's the simplest codewise, as there is no mapping required.
Of course, you won't be using SQLite at all.